# Getting access violation while creating logical devices

Tags: vulkan

I get the following error:

> Exception thrown at VkLayer_khronos_validation.dll
>   Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA5252DD05 (VkLayer_khronos_validation.dll) Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

My code:

```
void LogicalDevice::createLogicalDevice(VkPhysicalDevice pDevice){
VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo qcreateInfo;
qcreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_QUEUE_CREATE_INFO;
QueueFamiliesIndices indices = PhysicalDevice::findQueueFamilies(pDevice);
qcreateInfo.queueFamilyIndex = indices.graphicsFamily.value();
qcreateInfo.queueCount = 1;
float queuePriority = 1.0f;
qcreateInfo.pQueuePriorities = &queuePriority;

VkPhysicalDeviceFeatures deviceFeatures = {};

VkDeviceCreateInfo createInfo = {};
createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEVICE_CREATE_INFO;
createInfo.pQueueCreateInfos = &qcreateInfo;
createInfo.queueCreateInfoCount = 1;
createInfo.pEnabledFeatures = &deviceFeatures;

createInfo.enabledExtensionCount = 0;

if (ValidationLayers::enableValidationLayers){
     createInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(ValidationLayers::validationLayers.size());
     createInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = ValidationLayers::validationLayers.data();

}
else{
     createInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
     createInfo.pNext = nullptr;
}
createInfo.flags = 0;

if (vkCreateDevice(pDevice, &createInfo ,nullptr, &device) != VK_SUCCESS){
    std::cout << "Failed to create Logical Device";
}
```

}

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code.

Comment: Copy the code and paste it in a code block

Comment: Sorry, I am new in stackoverflow, I have changed it.

Comment: please be more clear about what you want

Comment: Exception only occur while building in debug mode so, I guess I have some problem with my validation layer but validation layer properly works for other cases. I don't know what is triggering this exception

Comment: Well, The problem might have been is that I hadn't passed any thing in flags and pnext, once I assigned it there was no crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninitialized `VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo`. Unitialized pointer (`pNext`) leads to bad pointer dereference. It happens in the Debug mode, because it uses debug memory pattern. In Release mode an uninitialized value often happens to be 0.

One of the typical ways to deal with this in C bindings of Vulkan is to zero-initialize `struct`s with `{}`. E.g. `VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo dqci = {};`. Or there are designated initializers in C99 and C++20. Zero is a decent default value for majority of Vulkan parameters.

Comment: I think you should clarify how {} initializes things, since it is possible the above user does not see that as an important step.

Comment: Sure, why not. It is not even a Vulkan-specific issue though, and I hope it is a typo. Anyone dealing with Vulkan should already have a decent handle on C/C++ or programming generally...

Comment: zero initialization via {}, even if taught is really only used for c structs like in vulkan with no proper constructors.  You can program in c++ your whole life with out encountering that initialization, vulkan was the first time in 5 years I had encountered that construct,  it is absolutely not typical.

Comment: Well, better late than never :p. As known, initialization in C++ is bonkers. Though uninitialized values is basic knowledge. The `{}` fix is but one way, and basically an opinion based suggestion from us.